# Issues installing scipy using Python

Tags: python, git, numpy, scipy

I've tried pip install scipy. I've tried all the suggestions on stackOverflow like updating pip, installing scipy manually through its website. I've tried getting it from github directly.

These are some of the errors I keep getting:

-When I try pip install:

```
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\us
ers\\kathyz~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-gmb8oc\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(com
pile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __f
ile__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\kathyz~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-gndjc
d-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" faile
d with error code 1 in c:\users\kathyz~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-gmb8oc\sci
py
```

-When I try through git:

```
    Exception: Cython either isn't installed or it failed.
    Cythonizing sources
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\kathyz~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-49aa2n-build\setup.py", lin
e 253, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "c:\users\kathyz~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-49aa2n-build\setup.py", lin
e 246, in setup_package
        generate_cython()
      File "c:\users\kathyz~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-49aa2n-build\setup.py", lin
e 164, in generate_cython
        raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed!")
    RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\us
ers\\kathyz~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-49aa2n-build\\setup.py';exec(compile(ge
tattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
'exec'))" install --record c:\users\kathyz~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-92weib-recor
d\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with
error code 1 in c:\users\kathyz~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-49aa2n-build
```

So after getting error about cythonize, I tried installing it, which led to another error:

```
warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'

warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'

warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Utility'
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: Are you sure scipy is not installed? I think I ran into this a couple weeks ago only discovering these errors to be not affecting the install.

Comment: Always try to google your error first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat.
The problem is that you need a `c/c++` compiler to build `scipy`. Using `anaconda` is one way to avoid this problem.